# Is it possible to combine fetch joins and COUNT in Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I want to fetch join some entities to avoid a lot of additional queries and I also want to get count of related collection.

Something like this:

```
SELECT u, a, count(p) properties_count
FROM User u
JOIN u.address a
LEFT JOIN u.properties p 
group by u.id
```

That is I want to get a collection like `[[0 => User, 'properties_count' => 42], [0 => ...], ...]`.

It works without fetch join (`SELECT u, count(p) properties_count`) but with `SELECT u, a, count(p) properties_count` it seems to not include count in the 
result.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was just a mistake in the original query.

It was using joins like this:

```
LEFT JOIN Address a WITH a.id = u.address
```

When I replaced this to

```
LEFT JOIN u.address a
```

it started working. (I thought they were equivalent)